# List of tuples with numbers and strings

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, which may look like this:

```
[(23, 'somestr'), (30, 'someotherstr'), (15, 'someotherstr2')]
```

I need to extract the tuple which has the minimum number, and get the string of that tuple. To find the minimum, I just did: `min([i[0] for i in list])`.

How would get the string though? A nested list comprehension? I've tried several ways but I',m not sure how to either retain the tuple's index, or get it within the list comprehension statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples can be compared:

```
>>> (1, 'hello') < (2, 'bye')
True
```

Tuples are compared kind of like strings: consider elements pairwise until you find an unequal pair, and then the tuple with the smaller element is considered smaller.

So you can simply get the minimum of the list, and the tuple with the lowest first value will be returned.  Then you can look at the string in the second element:

```
least = min(the_list)
print least[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
min(your_list)[1] #would be sufficient
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, you can just compare the tuples directly. However, a more general approach is to use the `key` argument to [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
In [21]: min(l, key=operator.itemgetter(0))[1]
Out[21]: 'someotherstr2'
```

Here, `key=operator.itemgetter(0)` extracts the zeroth element of the tuple and uses the result as the key to decide which tuple is the smallest.

Comment: key isn't required in this senario

Comment: @JakobBowyer: I think it's useful to show how this sort of thing is done in general, and that is the point of my answer.

Comment: But it doesn't *answer* the question.

Comment: @NPE what is `key-operator.itemgetter(0)` used for?

Comment: @JakobBowyer:  Could you spell this out for me?  It seems to me that it answers the question just fine.

Comment: @Darksky:  The `key` argument provides a function that is used to evaluate each item before comparing it.  `operator.itemgetter(0)` is equivalent in effect to `lambda tup: tup(0)`, but it is more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```
    python 3.2

    1. min(your_list)

    2. sorted(your_list)[0]

    3. min([(i,v) for i,v in your_list])
```